# Make code to wait before executing click() command

Tags: automated-testing, java, selenium-webdriver, uiautomation

I have a Java code that populates all the text fields automatically.
Before executing click() command for Submit button, I need to enter the Captcha manually. So I would like to make the code to wait for a few seconds so that I can enter the captcha.

Comment: If this is a website you control you're trying to test, you might want to mock out the Captcha (i.e. something like https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819902/mocking-away-captcha-field-when-testing-zend-form) so you can fully automate the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle CAPTCHA field in automation is extremely difficult and in some cases not possible. You can try one of the following to try and make your tests work,

1. Ask your dev team to set up a test environment where CAPTCHA is removed from the module you are testing, so that your tests can continue running without any problem.
2. Some CAPTCHA have a limited database and each image or text value has a unique ID. You can get the list of the IDs can match that to enter CAPTCHA value in the form.
3. Since you are using Java, you can use Thread.sleep() method to make the form wait for suffecient time before submitting the form so that you may enter the CAPTCHA code manually. But for this you will have to constantly examine the execution of your tests.
4. You can ask your dev team to add a hidden field with the available CAPTCHA value (Only for testing purpose, remove it before going live), which you can get in your script and have it inserted in CAPTCHA field.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Waiting for few seconds is fragile.

Your Java code is running in some terminal. Make it to prompt for for text input and wait. Entered input will be the solution of the CAPTCHA, which your code then enters to the page. Voila, you have as much time as you need to solve the CAPTCHA!

Of course even better solution would be to have special test instance of your system where CAPTCHA is disabled. But you already know that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask developer to display value in "Alt" attribute for testing purpose only. After testing is completed, we can remove value from alt.

You can automate captcha only using display captcha value in `alt` attribute.

1. Get the `WebElement` of captcha image
2. Fetch the value of `alt` attribute
3. Send `alt` value in text field